# Remove an attribute from XmlNode

Tags: c#, xml

how to remove an attribute from an System.Xml.XmlNode object in C#. The Code I tried did not work. It throw an exception "node to be removed is not valid child node"

```
foreach (XmlNode distribution 
         in responseXml.SelectNodes("/Distributions/Distribution/DistributionID"))
{
  XmlAttribute attribute = null;
  foreach (XmlAttribute attri in distribution.Attributes)
  {
    if (attri.Name == "GrossRevenue")
      attribute = attri;
  }
  if (attribute != null) 
    distribution.ParentNode.RemoveChild(attribute);
}
```

Comment: You should include the xml data so someone wishing to try your code could do so.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

XmlAttributes are not XmlNodes. `XmlNode.ChildNodes` is of type `XmlNodeList`, while `XmlNode.Attributes` is of type `XmlAttributesCollection`. To remove an attribute, you use the `XmlAttributesCollection.Remove` or `.RemoveAt` method. In your code:

```
distribution.ParentNode.Attributes.Remove(attribute);
```